# After Combining Join Table then Save/Append in other table

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, join

**Join two tables and save and add to current tables:**

Here is the scenario:

Everyday we need to to append or add the list of all records(Schedules and Dispatch) that we made into new Tables which is **RECORDS TABLES**.Then  after that **Schedules and Dispatch Table**  need to be delete all the data/records for that day.

I already made the the two tables join
here the code:

```
SELECT Dispatch.PlateNo, Dispatch.FirstName, Dispatch.LastName, Dispatch.MiddleName , Dispatch.TADDispatch, Schedules.LineNo, Schedules.DepartureTime, Schedules.DepartureTimes FROM Dispatch LEFT OUTER JOIN Schedules ON Dispatch.PlateNo = Schedules.PlateNo;
```

I don't have idea how to save or insert that into Records Tables and Delete all the data/record on Dispatch and Schedules

I'm using Microsoft Access and VB.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do the Insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO RECORDSTABLES
SELECT 
    Dispatch.PlateNo, Dispatch.FirstName, Dispatch.LastName, 
    Dispatch.MiddleName, Dispatch.TADDispatch, Schedules.LineNo, 
    Schedules.DepartureTime, Schedules.DepartureTimes
FROM 
    Dispatch LEFT OUTER JOIN Schedules ON Dispatch.PlateNo = Schedules.PlateNo
```

and then run a Truncate statement on your original two tables to delete the rows.

Comment: i think i have a problem if i will transfer this into vb.net